# Python Webapp2 GAE email send issue

Tags: python, email, google-app-engine, webapp2

I am working on a project in which I am sending an email to the user. In message body I am sending the custom message and it is working fine but when I add another variable for the link verification it did send the email but I do not receive it. But when I remove that link verification variable again it sends the email and I also receive it. Please help where I am doing mistake.

Here is the code which is working fine:

```
email = "a@gmail.com"
text = "from date: " + str(from_date) + " to date: " + str(to_date) + " Total Price: " + str(price)

message = mail.EmailMessage(
    sender="abc@gmail.com",
    subject="Booking Confirmation"
)

message.to = email
message.body = """Dear """ + name + """:
               """"""
               Please note date and time
               """ + text + """.

               Please let us know if you have any questions.
               """
message.send()
```

Here is the code which is not working:

```
email = "a@gmail.com"
text = "from date: " + str(from_date) + " to date: " + str(to_date) + " Total Price: " + str(price)
link = "http://abc.appspot.com/place/confirm/?place_id=" 
message = mail.EmailMessage(
    sender="abc@gmail.com",
    subject="Booking Confirmation"
)

message.to = email
message.body = """Dear """ + name + """:
               """+link+"""
               Please note date and time
               """ + text + """.

                Please let us know if you have any questions.
                """
message.send()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a mistake, the problem is including a link to an `*.appspot.com` domain, which, combined with being a new app (i.e. not yet trusted), triggers the now tighter Google infra anti-spam measures.

See [GAE Issue 12786](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=12786).

Contact the email address(es) mentioned in that thread if your app is not spamming, they probably have a hand-maintained whitelist for newer apps.